# spark - No schema defined, and no Parquet data file or summary file found under

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-spark

first I started

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
```

and write this code

```
sqlContext.load("jdbc", url="jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/test", driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", dbtable="test.test_tb")
```

**when I write only dbtable= "test_db", the error is same.**

After this error is occurred,

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o66.load.
>   : java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No schema defined, and no Parquet data file or summary file found under .
>   at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:179)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache.org$apache$spark$sql$parquet$ParquetRelation2$MetadataCache$$readSchema(newParquet.scala:429)
>   .....

why this error was occured??
I want to know and solve this problem.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason of this error, but I stumbled upon it, and then found a way to make the same thing work.

Try this:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://server/table?user=usr&password=secret", dbtable="table_name").load()
```

I suppose the `.load` syntax is no longer working, or does not work for jdbc. Hope it works!

By the way, I started the console with this command:

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=~/progs/postgresql-9.4-1205.jdbc42.jar pyspark
```

My db is in postgres, and so I downloaded the jar with the jdbc, and added it to my classpath as suggested in the documentation. 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases