# Error writing parquet file in S3 with Apache Spark in Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm using databricks to run my spark cluster( On-demand / Spark 1.6.0 (Hadoop 1) ), and using a scala notebook.

The fist time I try to create a parquet file in my S3 bucket with scala throw me this error:

`SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

But when I check my bucket the files are there, if I run again the cell with the same code, works fine, it seems like the first run always fail.

This is my code :

`data_frame.write.mode("append").partitionBy("date").parquet("s3n://...")`

Comment: This isn't an exception, it's related to the configuration of log4j. This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Did you read [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-9896) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174674/spark-no-schema-defined-and-no-parquet-data-file-or-summary-file-found-under)?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you are right is not an exception, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in the comments:

This isn't an exception, it's related to the configuration of log4j. This shouldn't be a problem. – Yuval Itzchakov